# How to prevent Custom Model Binder on some properties in model. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a custom model binder and registered it in Global.asax for decimal and decimal? types. I need to prevent it for some properties to bind values. How can I do it?
Look at the code below:

Globasl.asax

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(decimal)] = new DecimalModelBinder();
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(decimal?)] = new DecimalModelBinder();
```

DecimalModelBinder.CS

```
    public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    // adapted from: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1031:DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes")]
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (controllerContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("controllerContext");
        }

        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueProviderResult };

        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            var attemptedValue = (valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue ?? string.Empty)
                .Replace(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator, string.Empty)
                .Replace(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, string.Empty);

            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(attemptedValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(exception);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

TestViewModel.CS

```
    public class TestViewModel 
{


    [DisplayName("Percentage")]
    public decimal? Percent { get; set; }

    [FixedFeeRequired]
    [DisplayName("Fixed Fee")]
    public decimal? FixedValue { get; set; }
}
```

I want DecimalModelBinder to apply on one property only but I have registered it globally. Please suggest.

Comment: I think you should be able to bind it to a particular model instead of all models. check this - https://www.codeproject.com/articles/605595/asp-net-mvc-custom-model-binder I think this should help you, though I doubt if its possible for a particular field only.

Comment: this explanation is just about whole model. I have a long list of properties in my model so I can not write another Model Binder for it. I just need to prevent the DecimalModelBinder for few properties of type decimal.